# How do I show an svg in my navigation menu during mouseover?

Tags: jquery, css, html, svg

I'm trying to design a navigation menu with a hover over effect, the text is replaced with an svg.

This is what the menu currently looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/nCcs7/1/

I want to replace the text in the list item element with an svg on mouseover e.g.

```
<svg height="110" width="110">
<ellipse cx="55" cy="55" rx="50" ry="50" 
style="fill:crimson;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

I know you would have to use jQuery, but that's as far as I understand it.

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: You should not "replace" anything in your HTML. What you want is a pure "presentational effect", and therefore you should do it solely with CSS. That also has the advantage that the effect does not depend on JS enabled. Please also be aware of that your HTML markup is invalid. I gave you an example of how to possibly do it in my answer below. And do not let confuse you by the downvote - it's just because some people can not handle criticism! ;-)

Comment: It would have been nice if you had given a feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after I criticized some of the answers, I will post my proposal: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCcs7/7/)

Firstly I corrected the invalid HTML markup.
Secondly I put the SVG to the CSS to use it as a background-image.

The code for the (Base64 encoded) SVG is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
<ellipse cx="55" cy="55" rx="50" ry="50" fill="crimson" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill-rule="evenodd" />
</svg>
```

> I want to replace the text in the list item element with an svg on mouseove

No, you won't ...! ;-)
Instead you want to make the link elements `<a>` transparent on hover. By doing so you can set the desired background-color and -image to the list items `<li>`.

If I did not miss something, that's it.
Hope it helps.

PS: When dealing with SVGs here are just two links FYI.
- http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/
- http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCcs7/2/)

```
$text = ''
$( "a" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
  $text = $( this ).find( "li" ).text()
    $( this ).find( "li" ).html('<svg height="110" width="110"><ellipse cx="55" cy="55" rx="50" ry="50" style="fill:crimson;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg>');
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).find( "li" ).text( $text);
  });
```

Comment: No need to use Javascript here. And even though the OP asked for changing the HTML, this is not the right way to do it. Because it is a pure "presentational effect" here, so it all can be done solely with CSS, and also should be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using jquery

Here is example

**HTML**

```
<li>About<svg height="110" width="110">
<ellipse cx="55" cy="55" rx="50" ry="50" 
style="fill:crimson;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg></li>
```

**CSS**

```
 svg { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity:0}
    nav li:hover svg { opacity:1}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/nCcs7/3/

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Firstly your HTML is invalid, such as the original one of the OP (An un-/ordered list may only contain `li` elements as childs)! Secondly using inline SVG and repeating it on every list item is very ineffective and bloats the markup! Thirdly using the tag selector (svg) in CSS for positioning **all** SVG elements absolute and make them transparent isn't far from "ideal". Use a class or an id in the HTML to limit the CSS rules only to the appropriate SVG. Sorry, but this shouldn't really be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Netsurfer 
I know that ul can contain li as child but  First Check the fiddle provided in question..
I haven't changed any html I just added svg to li..
And also i just showed a way to do it..
There are many other ways....

Comment: And also @Netsurfer I you didn't liked my answer you could suggest me a edit.. I dont think you choose a wise way :/

Comment: @Netsurfer How would you recommend I go about this? I fixed my code so that the anchor is set correctly, here: http://jsfiddle.net/nCcs7/6/

Comment: @nonsequiter: I have added an answer on my own. If you have further questions please ask.

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery needed, just wrap them in common elements and use `:hover` to determine what to do

```
nav li:hover .text {
    display: none;
}
nav li:hover .svg {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav li .svg {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCcs7/4/

You'll probably wanna modify the styles a bit, but you get the gist of it. Simplest way possible.

Comment: Same as with Krunal Panchal's answer! It is not about answering a question as quickly as possible. Should be to point out to the questioner how to do things right and in a efficient way!